# onBeforeAction running too late

Tags: javascript, meteor, helper

I have a page with a helper that relies on a id_sell variable being set at routing with onBeforeAction. The issue currently is the helper runs before the variable is set.

```
this.route('/chat_id', {
    path: '/chat/:_id',
    template: 'Messages',
    layoutTemplate: 'LayoutMessages',
    onBeforeAction: function() {

      id = Session.get("recipientId");
      id_sell = this.params._id;
      this.next();
       }
    })
```

As you can see, this id_sell var is set here.

Unfortunately I get the error

> Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: id_sell is not defined

When my helper tries to load in the value of the global var.

How can I solve this loading error

Comment: If I understand you are trying to obtain the chat._id of the chat that is selected by the user? And then use it to pull a chat from the collection. Is this the idea?

Comment: I'm trying to get the id_sell var that is set in my routing BEFORE a helper runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using iron router, in which case you can change your route definition to

```
this.route('/chat_id', {
    path: '/chat/:_id',
    template: 'Messages',
    layoutTemplate: 'LayoutMessages',
    data: function() {
        return {
            id: this.params._id
        }
   }
})
```

and inside the `Messages` template you can access `Template.currentData().id` to access the variable.

Then, if you want to load something from the collection, you can change your route to

```
this.route('/chat_id', {
    path: '/chat/:_id',
    template: 'Messages',
    layoutTemplate: 'LayoutMessages',
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('messages');
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            id: this.params._id,
            messages: Messages.find({ chatId: this.params._id })
        };
    }
});
```

and template will then have `Template.currentData().messages` available and `{{#each messages}}` will work in html.

(obviously replacing `messages` and `Messages` with names of your publication and collection, accordingly).

Finally, you can pass the `this.params._id` into the `Meteor.subscribe(...)` call to only subscribe to the item you care about - but that is another story.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session in order to ger the value of this variable before the helper runs. For example,

> lib/router.js

```
Router.route('/chat/:_id', function(){
    Session.set("chatId", this.params._id);
    this.render("chatTemplate", {to:"main"});
});
```

> main.js

Here use:

```
var id_sell = Session.get("chatId");
```

And the variable will be set here before the helper runs.